# Did Rama pay any alimony or maintenance to Sita when he abandoned her?

Tags: rama, sita

In Ramarajya, one would expect husband to pay alimony or monthly maintenance to their wife if he abandons her.

Did Rama himself pay any alimony to Sita when he abandoned her in the forest?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.